# MODx Revo + Gallery + Ajax

Tags: modx, ajax, javascript, gallery

Добрый день.

Может, кто уже делал подобную вещь. Никак не могу осознать, как сделать LazyLoad (подгрузку блоков по мере скроллинга) для блоков, которые выводятся сниппетом Gallery.
Есть 100 .gal-item с содержимым. Для начала грузим 15, по мере скролла вниз подгружаем еще 15 и т.п.

Заткнулся на самом начале - рефакторинг php под MODx.
Может, есть у кого мысли или готовые решения. Очень буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Есть идея.
Вывод альбома по страницам осуществляется так:

```
        [[!getPage?
        &element=`Gallery`
        &limit=`8`
        &pageLimit=`3`
        &totalVar=`gallery.total`
        &pageNavVar=`page.nav`
         &album=`20` 
         &thumbWidth=`150` 
         &thumbHeight=`150` 
         &thumbQuality=`50` 
         &activeCls=`gallery-active` 
         &itemCls=`gallery-item`
         &imageWidth=`1024`
         &imageHeight=`900`
    ]]
```

Данный пример выведет 8 превьюшек из альбома с id 20.
Все, что тебе нужно, это сделать в отдельном ресурсе 
(например, `example.ru/albom&getAlbum=20&page=1`).

Без шаблона этот вывод и подгружать его через аякс или чем  ты там пользуешься, подставляя параметр `page=2`, `page=3`.
    То есть будет подгружаться на +1 больше.